# PHP Version showing 7.2 version in phpinfo.php file instead of PHP 7.4

Tags: php, ubuntu

Yesterday I updated my php version to 7.4 that was 7.2.
But even after changing all things, its showing 7.2 in my phpinfo.php file.

See this is php version when I run the command php --version in terminal.

```
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2020 07:24:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies 
     with Zend OPca che v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

And this is my phpinfo.php file

[image]

Please help me out!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your apache is using php 7.2.
If you are using ubuntu try this 
`sudo a2dismod php7.2` it will disable 7.2 version for apache
then `sudo a2enmod php7.4` it will enable 7.4 for apache
then `sudo service apache2 restart` to restart apache

Comment: Great.. It worked.

Comment: Welcome @Rohit.